# Sumar registros por meses en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Les explico, tengo una tabla con el nombre Ingresos y dentro de ella las columnas (id, concepto, monto, categoria_id, fecha, created_ay y update_at), entonces lo que yo quiero es que de esa tabla se sume todos los registros del mes actual (Mayo -> 05) para que yo en el Dashboard poder mostrar algo como "Ingresos registrados en el mes -> $ XXXX.XX". Entonces, les comento algo curioso y en donde radica mi problema, como pueden ver tengo un array, "'date' => date('m')" donde 'date' es el nombre de la tabla con formato date (aaaa-mm-dd) entonces si yo ese 'date' lo cambio por categoria_id y hay registros con el valor 5 funciona, osea me suma todos los registros con valor 5 que es igual al mes en el que actualmente estamos. Pero no puedo hacerlo con 'date'.

Espero haberme dejado entender, y tambien espero su apoyo.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Controlador:

```
 public function index(){             
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Lima');
    $ingresos_mes = Ingresos::where(array('date' => date('m')))->sum('monto');
    
    return view('dashboard', compact('ingresos_mes', 'ingreso'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si como mencionas *date* es la columna con formato *yyyy-mm-dd*, entonces es normal que no te muestre resultado alguno pues tu query en la condición se podría leer algo como esto:

```
donde '2021-05-10' sea igual a '05'
```

Lo cual por su puesto te debería dar false pues no existe la igualdad indicada, debes buscar la opción que de la fecha guardada te permita solo extraer la sección del mes para tener algo como esto:

```
donde '05' sea igual a '05'
```

La forma mas simple en que lo puedes obtener es:

- Usa la función [*`whereMonth`*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) de esta forma:

  ```
  Ingresos::whereMonth('date', '05')->sum('monto');
  ```
- O de manera dinámica obteniendo el mes vía la instancia de la clase *Carbon* así:

  ```
  Ingresos::whereMonth('date', now()->month)->sum('monto');
  ```
- Por otro lado no necesitas declarar el *timezone* a nivel del controlador, en su lugar:

  - Dentro de la carpeta raíz de tu proyecto busca la carpeta *config*, luego busca el archivo llamado *app*, aquí vas a encontrar un *array asociativo* entonces ubica la clave: *`timezone`* y justo ahi agrega el *string* correspondiente.

    ```
    'timezone' => 'aqui_tu_timezone',
    ```

Comment: gracias por responder y por ayudarme con esto que me tenia liado todo el dia, utilice `Ingresos::whereMonth('date', now()->month)->sum('monto');` y me funciona perfectamente. Gracias. Ahora con respecto a lo ultimo, si lo intente pero por una razon que desconozco no me funciona actualmente lo tengo asi `'timezone' => 'America/Lima'`